# simpledb vs cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra, amazon-simpledb

I've used both simpedb and cassandra, and I've read some article about cassandra.It seems that compared to simpledb, cassandra does not allow flexible data model. I mean, in cassandra the  the composition of column family must be specified explicitly, while in simpledb, you do not need to specify that, each record can have different count of value which correspond to different count of columns. Am I right and is that a big difference between them? Is it their internal mechanisms which result in such difference?

Answer (score 2):

Actually Cassandra and SimpleDB have very similar data models. Cassandra also allows for sparse columns (not every column needs to exist in every row) as well as very wide rows. Technically you can have 2 billion columns per row, although the practical limitation is usually much lower. Hundreds of thousands of columns per row is not uncommon.

For a better understanding of Cassandra's data model see: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/ddl/index